# My war file doesn't deploy well in tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, war

I have a question about deploy my war in tomcat.

I can deploy my war app in my local (I use command maven: tomcat7:run) and I don't have any problem, but when I deploy this war in my tomcat 7 server that it's in amazon web service and it has a default installation, only I have put in tomcat user (%TOMCAT7_PATH%/conf/tomcat-users.xml)

```
<tomcat-users>

    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />

</tomcat-users>
```

and server.xml

```
<Context path="appname" docBase="path of my-application deployed folder"/>
```

When I access to my url (url:8080/appname), the browser give me 404 not found (HTTP Status 404 - / The requested resource is not available)

Do I have to do something more?

Comment: You shouldn't use `server.xml` to deploy contexts. Can you not drop your WAR file into Tomcat's auto-deployment directory (`webapps/`)?

Comment: Thanks you so much. I found my problem. It was incompatibility with jdk. My code was compiled with java8 and server had java7, I upgraded the version and it worked.